# How to get properies of a relationship as comma separated values in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `ManyToMany` relationship for example Facility and Home so here is the example of the relationship:

```php
public function facility()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(facility::class)->withPivot('is_free');
}
```

and in `facility` I have:

```php
public function home()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Home::class)->withPivot('is_free');
}
```

and in some `controller` I do like below :

```php
$data = Home::with('facility')->get;
```

it gives me the **result** like below :

```
{
    name: example,
    id: 1,
    facility: {
        id: 1,
        name:item1,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name:item1,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name:something,
    }
}
```

now i want it **comma separated** like below :

```
{   
    name:example,
    id : 1,
    some other fileds ,
    ,
    , 
         facility: {item1,item2,item3,item4,. . .
    }
}
```

so I want them comma separated and only pick some certain columns from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [a custom attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this.

```
public function getFacilityDataAttribute()
{
    return implode(", ", $this->facility->getAttributes());
}
```

And inside Home class:

```
class Home extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['facility_data'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the results for facility, you can do this.

```
public function facility()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(facility::class)->withPivot('is_free')->where('some_field','some_value');
}
```

if you want to join the results by comma, you can do this.

```
foreach($homes as $home) {
  $home->computed_field = $home->facility->pluck('name')->implode(',');
}
```

Comment: i dont want to restrict i want jus the name of all facilites to be showed but comma seperated

Comment: just as the question i posted

Comment: you can use implode on the collection to join by comma

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: $data = Home::with('facility')->get;
 i want to show it in here $data in this line i get it on with key as u see